# How can I use \textsc inside a \documentclass (poster) option?

Tags: small-caps, posters, documentclass

I am using a quite nice looking poster template I found [here](https://nl.overleaf.com/latex/templates/dtu-poster/nfchvswyhcnq) to base my poster on. However, I want to use `\textsc{}` in my title, and the template won't let me. I get the following error:

```
Argument of \@fileswith@pti@ns has an extra }. \usepackage
```

Here is a MWE (it may contain too much information but I don't know what might be relevant for my issue and what not; sorry about that):

```
\documentclass[
    ,title     = {{\textsc{In small caps}: Not in small caps}}
    ,author    = {{ThisIs MyName}}
    ,toplogo   = {{uni-logo}}
    ,papersize = {{a0paper}}
    ,colcount  = {{3columns}}
    ,longtitle
    ,nocrop
]{dtuposter}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        % special characters
%\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}  % Windows
%\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc} % MacOS
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}    % Unicode, Linux

\usepackage{cmbright}
\usepackage{arevmath}
%\usepackage[scaled]{uarial} %Arial clone, set as default sf font - use "ua1" for direct access
%\usepackage{uarial} %Arial clone, set as default sf font - use "ua1" for direct access
%\usepackage[typeface=default,
%            sanstypeface=urwarial,
%            mathtypeface=arevmath
%           ]{typeface}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{nosep,leftmargin=*}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
```

[This](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-extrabrace) page leads me to believe that the problem lies in the fact that I am trying to place the `\textsc` command inside another command, but the solutions given there do not solve it.

Elsewhere on the internet I have found that it might be because the font I am using is not compatible with `\textsc`, but I am not sure how to solve that. One solution I found was to use

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

which I am already doing, and which does not help.

I am on Windows, but uncommenting

```
%\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}  % Windows
```

and commenting out the one below that is currently used did not help.

I use MiKTeX 2.9.

Comment: First of all you are always more likely to get help is you post a full but minimal self contained example others can copy and test as is. Also the utf8x option should not be used, use utf8

Comment: Not the cause of the error, but are you sure the font you're using has small-caps anyway? Most sans-serifs don't. If you're using `cmbright`, it doesn't as far as I can tell.

Comment: @cfr You are right - it doesn't. See also my edit for the follow-up question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question: as pointed out by `cfr` in one of the comments, the font I am using (`cmbright`) does not support small capitals (nor does it support simultaneous use of bold and italics).

So I thought I could fake it by doing something like this:

```
S\footnotesize{MALL}\normalsize{C}\footnotesize{APS}
```

which works in section headers (using `\protect`), but not in the `title` option of the `documentclass`:

```
\documentclass[
    ,title     = {{S\footnotesize{MALL}\normalsize{C}\footnotesize{APS}: Not in small caps}}
```

This does not compile, and gives the following error at the command `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`:

```
Undefined control sequence. \usepackage
```

From this I understand that I cannot use `\normalsize`, `\footnotesize` etc. before specifying that I am using the package `fontenc`.

Comment: Is this an answer, an edit or a followup question? Asking questions in the answer space makes no sense. The problem isn't that you can't use size commands without loading `fontenc`. The size commands are part of LaTeX itself. They don't take arguments, by the way.

Comment: @cfr This was an answer, but some questions crept in. I removed them.

Comment: The answer is wrong. The size commands are not provided by `fontenc`. (They also do not take arguments.) What the cause of the error is is impossible to say without further information, but `title` is not a standard class option at all, and we don't know which class you're specifying.